# Scroll Speed Disparity Android 2D Graphics

Tags: android, graphics, bitmap

I am experimenting with 2D graphics in Android during my off time, and I'm intrigued by the idea of creating a sprite based "sandbox" for playing around.  I've looked around online and found some good tutorials, but I'm stuck with a fairly basic problem: My sprite moves faster than the terrain and "glides" over it.  Also, he slowly outpaces the terrain scrolling and moves to the edge of the view.

I've got an animated sprite that I want to move around the world.  I do so by changing his absolute coordinates(setting X and Y position in an 'update()' function and applying a scalar multiple to speed up or slow down the rate at which he's moving around.

```
this.setXPos(currX + (speed * dx2));
this.setYPos(currY + (speed * dy2));
```

Underneath that sprite, I'm drawing "terrain" from a bitmap.  I want to continue to move that sprite around via the coordinate accessors above, but also move my view and scroll the terrain so that the sprite stays in the same relative screen location but moves through the "world".  I have an imperfect implementation where `player` is my sprite and `field` is my terrain:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
     player.updateLocation(GameValues.speedScale);
     field.update(new Point(player.getXPos(), player.getYPos()));

     field.draw(canvas);
     player.draw(canvas);
     //more stuff here...
}
```

And `field.update()` looks like(**Warning: Hard-coded scariness**):

```
public void update(Point pt)
{

    sourceRect.left = pt.x - 240;
    sourceRect.right = pt.x + 240;

    sourceRect.top = pt.y - 400;
    sourceRect.bottom = pt.y + 400;
}
```

The thinking there was that I would eventually just get screen dimensions and make it less 'hack-y', but get something together quickly.  This could easily be where my issue is coming from.  Of immediate interest is `field.draw()`:

```
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas)
{
   try
   {
      canvas.drawBitmap(fieldSheet, sourceRect, destRect, null);
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
      //Handle Exception...
   }
}
```

You'll notice I'm using the overload of `drawBitmap()` that accepts a source and destination Rect and that the `field.update()` method moves that sourceRect to match the movement of the sprite.  How can I keep the "camera (so to speak)" centered on the sprite and scroll the terrain appropriately?  I had thought that moving just the sourceRect and maintaining a constant destRect would do so, but now I'm thinking I have to move the destRect around the "world" with the sprite, while maintaining the same dimensions.

Is there a better (read **functional**) way of making this work?  I'm coming here somewhat shamefully, since I think this should be somewhat easier than it seems to be for me.  Any and all help or suggestions are appreciated.  Thanks!

***Edit:***Does it make sense to also move the destination `Rect` at the same speed as the sprite?  I think I conflated the source and destination `Rect`'s and left the destRect immobile.  I'll update with the results after I get a chance to try it (maybe during lunch).

***Edit_2:***Changing the destination rectangle didn't get me there, but using the `View.scrollBy(x, y)` method gets me close to totally satisfied.  The remaining question to be satisfied is how to "clip" the View scrolling to a rectangle that represents the "field".  I believe that the `View.getLeft()` and `View.getTop()` functions, offset by the screen width and height, can be used to specify a `Rect` that can be virtually moved around within the constraints of the "world" and block further deltas from being argued to the `View.scrollBy()` method.  The reason I look toward this approach is because the `View` doesn't seem to be positioned in absolute space, and a `View.getLeft()` call, even after a `View.scrollBy(x, y)` where x > 0, returns a 0.